KEEPFILTERS seems to be ignored
Please, help me, since I'm stuck and unable to figure this out:
I have a table:

Column [MaxCode] is a Measure:
MaxCode =  CALCULATE(
 MAX('Opleidingen_MW'[Code]),
ALLEXCEPT('Opleidingen_MW', Opleidingen_MW[Medewerker]) 
    )

Now I want to filter [Begin_date] and (re-)calculate MaxCode while retaining the date-filter.
So, for example, [Begin_date] < 1-1-2020 should look like:

This is my DAX (but it doesn't work; the date filter is not retained in de results for [MaxCode]:
MaxCode = CALCULATE(
     MAX('Opleidingen_MW'[Code]),
        KEEPFILTERS(Opleidingen_MW[Begindatum_opleiding]),
         ALLEXCEPT('Opleidingen_MW', Opleidingen_MW[Medewerker])
     )

I've tried all kind of ways, but it won't work?
What is the DAX-code for dynamically calculating the [MaxCode] per Empl. while preserving the [begin_date] filter?
thnx!!
I tried to make a measure that calculates the MaxCode per Empl. while retaining a start-date filter using KEEPFILTERS. However, the applied start-date filter appears to be ignored.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you posted a well phrased question. Consider reviewing https://stackoverflow.com/tour if you have not already. Also, it is generally considered better to post tables as text rather than images (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Good luck!

[MaxCode] is a calculated column, not a measure (it looks like you are confusing these two concepts). Calculated columns do not respond to filters, only measures.

here is a workaround.

use DAX to create a new date table and use the column in the date table to filter the data.
date = DISTINCT('Table'[Begin_date])

create relationship between original table and date table

create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _start =
MIN ( 'date'[Begin_date] )
VAR _max =
MAX ( 'date'[Begin_date] )
RETURN
MAXX (
FILTER (
ALL ( 'Table' ),
'Table'[Begin_date] >= _start
&& 'Table'[Begin_date] <= _max
&& 'Table'[Empl] = MAX ( 'Table'[Empl] )
),
'Table'[Code]
)



